# OS X TreeView paint

Tags: macos, qt

I used a `QStyledItemDelegate` (Qt5) to paint an `QPixmap` on a `QTreeView` row when I hover it.

```
void ActionsItemDelegate::paint(
    const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
    const QModelIndex& selectedProxy) const
{
    QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, option, selectedProxy);
    if (option.state & QStyle::State_MouseOver)
    {
        Draw qpixmap ...
    }
}
```

It's working as expected on Windows and Linux, but I can't get it to work on OS X 10.11. `paint()` is simply not called on hover on OS X. It's called when I click on a row, when the window is resized, etc. I found that:

- Windows highlights the row on hover
- Linux (Mint, at least) hightlights the checkbox on hover
- OS X doesn't change any pixel on hover, so it doesn't call `paint()` because there's no need

Any other Window Manager could do the same as OS X. I can't test them all. Is there a way to ensure that `paint()` will be called on hover even when the OS doesn't require it?

Comment: Implementing `paint` is only half the job. The other half is invoking `update()` in reaction to mouse events. This may require adding an event filter on the view.

Comment: @KubaOber Yes, I read that somewhere else too, but I'm asking on SO because I need information on how and where to do it. An example will help all the other programmers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a [probably bad] solution to my problem.

```
#ifdef __APPLE__
    treeView->setStyleSheet("QTreeView::item:hover{}");
#endif
```

As you can see, I added an empty css declaration on `QTreeView::item:hover`, which tricks Qt into calling `paint()` whenever the mouse is over an item.

The `#ifdef` is not even required as it's not breaking anything on the other OSes.

- I tested quickly and **think** `paint()` is called as often as before
- It's not changing the default UI style on other OSes because the css declaration is empty.

I can't say I'm a fan of this solution though. It does look like a hack. An empty css declaration shouldn't change anything. Qt could fix this "bug" on a future version and it would stop working.

Comment: It's a very clever solution. Given that the widgets module is in long-term maintenance, this will probably keep on working forever.